# I need to pass a JSON object to a javascript/ajax method for a WCF call. How can I do this?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

So I have been looking around at many different examples of such a thing.  Most people are using a JSON serializer/deserializer or stringify method.  I have attempted to try a similar thing and unfortunately I always get an error from Google's Chrome debugger console saying:
Uncaught ReferenceError: JavaScriptSerializer is not defined or something similar.

Below is the actual method where I try to do a PUT operation using the information.

```
  function insertjsonMyUser(person) {

        document.write("Inside the parameter based insertion method<br/>");
        alert("Entered the method, right before the ajax call");
        $.ajax({
            type: "PUT",
            url: 'http://localhost/MyService/Service.svc/json/CreateUserInfo',
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: {"User" : person.User ,"Pword" : person.Pword,"FName" : person.FName,"LName" : person.LName,"JobTitle" : person.JobTitle,"CompanyName" : person.CompanyName,"CompanyBranch" : person.CompanyBranch,"PhoneNum" : person.PhoneNum,"Email" : person.Email},
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'default default');
            }
        });
        alert("The user has been created according to your specifications");

}
```

I want person to be a JSON object using the specified Keys I have under data.  I have successfully done a similar method, but I don't want to use a hard-coded JSON object such as:

```
{"User" : "Zuser" ,"Pword" : "password","FName" : "firstname","LName" : "lastname","JobTitle" : "jobtitle","CompanyName" : "companyname","CompanyBranch" : "companybranch","PhoneNum" : 3123123123,"Email" : "email"}
```

The JSON object I use in the hard-coded version is the object above.  Is there something I am missing for using the methods stringify or serialize?  Also, is there an easier way than those that I have missed in my hours of searching?

Finally, I am running Windows 7 Enterprise, using IIS hosting, and using Visual Studio 2010 for editing. My Service works fine.  I tested it in Fiddler successfully.

Comment: Unrelated, but worth noting: `$.ajax()` is asynchronous. Your second alert will execute *before* the service call completes. If you start doing something meaningful after the call, that could trip you up.  To run code *after* the call completes, use `$.ajax()`'s `success` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I have finally figured out my own question's answer.  The reason that the actual parameter passing did not work was single quotes.  When I declared my actual JSON object, I declared it as:

```
{"User" : "Zuser" ,"Pword" : "password","FName" : "firstname","LName" : "lastname","JobTitle" : "jobtitle","CompanyName" : "companyname","CompanyBranch" : "companybranch","PhoneNum" : 3123123123,"Email" : "email"}
```

I actually needed to declare it as:

```
'{"User" : "Zuser" ,"Pword" : "password","FName" : "firstname","LName" : "lastname","JobTitle" : "jobtitle","CompanyName" : "companyname","CompanyBranch" : "companybranch","PhoneNum" : 3123123123,"Email" : "email"}'
```

I guess it is possible to append the single quotes onto the actual object in the method itself, but you can just do the actual declaration as I did to get around the problem.

Answer (score 1):

well

```
 contentType: "application/json",
 data: person,
 beforeSend: ....
```

Will this work ?

From http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ , data can be an object or string.

Comment: Unfortunately that runs into a different error than the stringify and serialization.  The error I get for that one is:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there might be an error in your WCF service not finding JavascriptSerializer.  Do you compile on one machine and deploy it to another?  They might not be synched up .NET library wise.

Also, please add the exact error message you are getting, that will be very helpful.

Comment: I built the service on the same machine as the IIS hosting machine.  I am trying to use an external html page with the above javascript to access the Service.  They are both located within C:\inetpub\wwwroot but then they each have a separate folder within the wwwroot folder.

As for the exact error messages, I have included an example error message straight from Chrome's console.  Perhaps there is a better error message from elsewhere?


Also, I am not set to use just a serializer or deserializer.  Any way that would allow access would be much appreciated.